# MySQL - BTree AND Hash indexes for the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, b-tree-index

I have tried finding similar questions but didn't find any, except questions regarding two indexes for the same column (in general).

Let us assume we have a table with a column `COL`. The table (and the entire database) is read-only for clients (let us assume it is updated once/once every long periods of time and only by a backend service). Therefore, insertion/update time is irrelevant.

For this column, there are highly used queries which search for rows where the `COL` value is in some range, and some more highly used queries that search for rows where `COL` is compared directly with a value (equality check).

Is it beneficial, giving the above, to hold both a `BTREE` and `HASH` index on `COL`? Will the optimizer use the `BTREE` index for the range queries and the `HASH` index for the direct comparison queries?
Will the answer change if `COL` is of type `varchar(256)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with the B-Tree index, because you need it anyway.  There could possibly be some minor performance gain from using a hash index as well, but you are also going to be occupying more memory.

More importantly, hash indexes are not available for the most common storage engines (InnoDB and MyISAM) -- Table 13.1 in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html).

Comment: How can we best evaluate the gain in performance (with the hash index) vs the extra memory the index will take?
When will we prefer choosing to add the index in order to gain the performance improvement?

Comment: @Mickey . . . You would run timings using each of the indexes on queries that would use the index.  That will give you an idea of how beneficial they are.  However, the fact that hash indexes are not available on the most common storage engines seems like a rather serious consideration.

Comment: as an example, hash indexes are great if you use in-memory tables on which you perform equality operations ( = or <=> ) further down in your transaction. (eg. WHERE inMemoryTable.hashIndexedColumnFOO = 'BAR')